# Chrome 41 password saving makes wrong choice when used with Dojo validation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dojo

Chrome's "Save Password" feature apparently makes a simple choice when offering to remember passwords:  It looks at the value of the previous input field in the DOM and offers to key the password to that value.   So if you have this username/password combo:

```
<form>
    <input value="myname" />
    <input value="mypassword" />
</form>
```

the browser will offer to save the password "mypassword" under the key "myname".

This presents a problem when using Dojo ValidationTextBox however, because the Dojo parser inserts an invisible INPUT control that contains a character "X" used as a validation icon (simplified HTML view):

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input value="X" />
        <input value="myname" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input value="X" />
        <input value="mypassword" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Under this circumstance Chrome offers to remember "mypassword" under the name of "X", which is awkward.

Is it possible to override this behavior in Chrome?   Or do we need to rewrite this functionality in Dojo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `name` properties to the validation widgets:

```js
this.username = new ValidationTextBox({ name: 'username' });
this.password = new ValidationTextBox({ name: 'password' });
```

Or declaratively:

```html
<input type="text" name="username" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" />
<input type="text" name="password" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" />
```

This will produce nodes with name attributes which Chrome will be able to use to associate the value with a key. Your simplified HTML view would then look like this:

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <input value="X" />
        <input name="username" value="myname" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input value="X" />
        <input name="password" value="mypassword" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does not work for me.. Chrome always wants to save an 'X' as username. The password is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how you can make this to work. When you use the name attribute with the appropiate values(username, password) the username value will be the input value above the password input.

### 1. Surround your fields with a form

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" autocomplete="username" data-dojo-props="selectOnClick: true, uppercase: true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" required="required" />
</form>
```

### 2. Add an autocomplete to your input field with the value 'username' and 'password'

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="username" data-dojo-props="selectOnClick: true, uppercase: true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" required="required" />
<input type="password" autocomplete="password" data-dojo-props="selectOnClick: true, uppercase: true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" required="required" />
```

### 3. Add a button to submit or just a regular button

```
<input type="submit" value="send" />
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/3bfkbahd/1/)